# Why am I getting an infinite loop?

Tags: loops, infinite

My output prints positive or negative repeatedly. Why am I getting an infinite loop? I used the following:

```
include iostream 
using namespace std; 

int main()
{
    int num;

    cout<<"enter number"<<endl;
    cin>>num;

    while(num!=0)
    {
        if(num>0)
            cout<<"positive"<<endl;
        else
            cout<<"negative"<<endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on madflame991's answere here is an improved version :)

```
include iostream 
using namespace std; 

int main()
{
    int num;

    do
    {
        cout<<"enter number"<<endl;
        cin>>num;

        if(num>0)
            cout<<"positive"<<endl;
        else
            cout<<"negative"<<endl;
    }while(num!=0);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you have `while(num!=0)` and there's nothing that may alter its value in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

The value of `num` doesn't change in the body of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You should change the value of `num` inside the loop, because the condition of the while-loop will never become false.

Answer (score 0):

You need to read the value while in the loop too. If you don't then **num** won't change and will remain forever the same and hence you either get an infinite loop or nothing (for num==0)

```
{int num;

cout<<"enter number"<<endl;
cin>>num;

while(num!=0)
{
    cout<<"enter number"<<endl;
    cin>>num;

    if(num>0)
        cout<<"positive"<<endl;
    else
        cout<<"negative"<<endl;
}
return 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because of the logic of your code. You first read a number from standard input and then construct a while loop based on a condition that the number not equals 0. So if the value of num supplied via a standard input is not equal to 0 you program will repeat the body of the loop again and again.

In this code the while loop itself is not needed. If just wanted to print a message to user based on whether the num is positive/negative, you could just leave the if / else part and get rid of the while loop like this:

```
    using namespace std; 
    int main() {

    int num;

    cout<<"enter number"<<endl;
    cin>>num;

    while(num!=0)
    {
        if(num>0)
            cout<<"positive"<<endl;
        else
            cout<<"negative"<<endl;
    }

    return 0; 
}
```

Another possiblity would be the user opportunity to enter the num multiple times and break the while loop on certain condition like this:

```
using namespace std; 
int main() {

int num;

do {
cout<<"enter number"<<endl;
cin>>num;
   if(num>0)
        cout<<"positive"<<endl;
    else if(num < 0)
        cout<<"negative"<<endl;
} while(num!=0);

return 0;
```

}

Here the loop will finish if the num equals to 0. You could also explicitly break out of the loop with `break` statement based on some condition.